# Why does `do_send` method not get handled in `actix` where a `send` is?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

Mostly interested in what am I missing in my actix mental model, thank you in advance!
Here is a pretty rudimentary actix example with ping pong messages and corresponding responses:

```rust
#[derive(Message)]
#[rtype(result = "Responses")]
enum Messages {Ping,Pong}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Responses {GotPing,GotPong}

impl<A, M> MessageResponse<A, M> for Responses
where
    A: Actor,
    M: Message<Result = Responses>
{
    fn handle(self, _ctx: &mut A::Context, tx: Option<OneshotSender<M::Result>>) {
        if let Some(tx) = tx {tx.send(self);}
    }
}
```

And here is main:

```rust
#[actix_rt::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let addr           = ActorQuox.start();
    let pongfut_async  = addr.send(Messages::Pong).await;
    pongfut_async.map_or(Responses::GotPong, |res| {
        println!("Got result: {:?}", res);
        res
    });

    let ping  = addr.do_send(Messages::Ping);
}
```

Whereas i would expect the output to be:

```
Got message
Got result: GotPong
Got message
```

It is actually:

```
Got message
Got result: GotPong
```

I'm not sure how to reason about this given that i think that the handler `impl Handler<Messages> for ActorQuox` i supposed to fire on all three of `do_send`, `send` and `try_send` given that they all do `tx.send(self)` in their implementations on `Addr` and the difference is only in the return signatures. I'm obviously wrong about this or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can't `.await` a [`do_send()`](https://docs.rs/actix/latest/actix/prelude/struct.Addr.html#method.do_send), the execution continues and will exit `main()`. This will cause the async runtime created by `#[actix_rt::main]` to shut down and will not complete any pending tasks.

You can add a [`sleep()`](https://docs.rs/actix-rt/2.7.0/actix_rt/time/fn.sleep.html) call and you'd probably see it.